# How to properly setup composer within PHP Apache Docker Container

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, composer

Content of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1-apache

WORKDIR /var/www/html/

RUN pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && a2enmod rewrite \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
COPY composer.json composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.lock

RUN groupadd -r user && useradd -r -g user user
USER user
RUN composer install --no-dev

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80
```

The composer installation fails at the point where it's telling me that the `libzip` package is needed. I can however not find that package, no matter if via `pecl`, via `apt-get`; as most of the forum posts refer to. How can I Install `libzip` to finally get things running?

A few notes on my Dockerfile lines; feel free to correct me if I'm wrong in the setup; it's the first time I'm doing this:

```
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
COPY composer.json composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.lock
```

As I understood it, the [official docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/composer) tell you to use this multi-stage approach to get composer running in your PHP Docker container in an optimal way. If I understood it correctly, doing it in this way allows you to share your image without your colleagues needing to install composer / download the packages locally; everything will then be done within the container. Which is exactly what I'm looking for.

```
RUN groupadd -r user && useradd -r -g user user
USER user
RUN composer install --no-dev
```

I first tried to simply run the last line `composer install --no-dev`, which actually won't work, as the container won't let you execute root commands; used by default by `composer`. Hence the reason for this workaround (changing the user is also what the official docs recommend; according to the link above).

`&& docker-php-ext-install zip`

When finally able to run the `composer install` command within the container, it told me that the `zip` extension is needed; which is why I've added the `docker-php-ext-install zip` command. Now I'm stuck due to the initially mentioned `libzip` issue.

If you see a better way to setup composer; I'm happy to hear about a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker-php-ext-enable` is looking for the libzip **header files**. What you need is the package `libzip-dev`.

```
RUN pecl install xdebug \
    && apt update \
    && apt install libzip-dev -y \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && a2enmod rewrite \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Comment: Great, cheers, that works! The only problem now is that there's no `vendor` folder in my container root??

Comment: That would be a new question. The relevant output from the build would probably be helpful.